# Is there a TUI OSK for linux or node.js?

Tags: linux, node.js, terminal-emulator

Basically what I am looking for is a text-interface on-screen keyboard that runs in a terminal session over ssh etc. using xterm-style mouse-clicks (escape sequences), no gui.  That would enable it to be used on mobile terminals via touch-screen, as on a tablet or phone without installing a special IME for 101-key support, though it need not be advertised for this.

Generally I use Hacker's Keyboard, but I've put together an https/ssh terminal that it might be useful for, which uses touch and/or mouse via xterm escapes.  I wrote a GUI OSK for it as well, but have found other convienient uses for a TUI OSK.

Anyone ever hear of this?

My search terms are all bombarding me with how to install or run a regular GUI-based OSK from the command-line, but what I'm looking for would run in the terminal with a split-window, sort of like 'screen' or tmux, in order to have a keyboard in one, and a shell or other program on top.